# R Blogdown with different Rmarkdown outputs

Tags: r-markdown, flexdashboard, blogdown

I built a blogdown site using Hugo and it has multiple sections, posts all written in Rmarkdown with outputs designed as html_document. It works fine.

In parallel, I designed an HTML dashboard using Rmarkdown with an output designed as flex_dashboard. It generates an HTML file working fine.

I wanted to integrate the dashboard directly within the building of the site but unfortunately by simply adding the Rmarkdown file in the blogdown structure it knits it as an html document and not as a flex_dashboard. So, I have the content within my website but not at all as dashboard but more like a traditional html_document. So no luck with that :(

I tried then copying the dashboard html under /static/html and create a brand new Rmarkdown just  invoking my html within an iframe:

```
--- 
output: html_document
---
<link rel="preload" href="/html/OpenDashboard.html" as="document">
<iframe width="100%" height="600" name="iframe" src="/html/OpenDashboard.html"></iframe>
```

Looked good to me and was pretty happy even in inelegant but performance is bad. It takes a long time to load (+10sec) even if the file is not that big (only 6Mb). Size of the html will grow a lot in the future and I can't hope viewers will wait that long.

I read it was possible to clarify the type of knitting we want within a build.R file but I am clueless on how to specify I want html_document knitting for some Rmarkdowns and flex_dashboard for some others.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question: in Section 2.7 of the **blogdown** book, it mentions that you could use `blogdown::build_dir()` in `R/build.R` to build arbitrary Rmd files under the `static/` directory.

Comment: I tried putting the Rmd file under a static/flexdashboard folder. Creating the build.R file under R folder with blogdown::build_dir() code did indeed create the .html under static/flexdashboard. However what gets copied to the public folder is also the html files and it does not render properly as there is no index.html file created.